# Deleting file in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, delete-file, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to delete a file stored in my `storage/app/public` directory.
I'm trying to retrieve the file path from database and delete it, but it's not working.

```
$file = Blog::where('id', $id)->pluck('image');

Storage::delete($file);
```

I'm retrieving the file's path successfully:

```
echo $file = Blog::where('id', $id)->pluck('image');
```

because the above line gets me this:

```
["public\/blog\/tLL0JoDmAKadTL0SqFZp1Is4oAK3YUo0GjOWB3fh.jpeg"]
```

so I thought something is wrong with using the storage facade and the delete method, and I tried this:

```
Storage::delete(["public\/blog\/tLL0JoDmAKadTL0SqFZp1Is4oAK3YUo0GjOWB3fh.jpeg"]);
```

but it worked...
and I'm really confused why I can't use the variable!

Comment: are you in windows or linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel pluck returns an eloquent collection and not an array.
Try converting the collection to an array using the `all()` or `toArray()` functions

```
$file = Blog::where('id', $id)->pluck('image')->all();
```

Or

```
$file = Blog::where('id', $id)->pluck('image')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
$file = Blog::where('id', $id)->first()->image;
Storage::delete($file);
```